# Rspec mocking, verify that received objects are not the same

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I have a method that is duplicating a variable and distributing it to different objects. I would like to verify that the objects that are being sent is indeed different objects, and not different pointers to the same object.

My test currently looks like this:

```
it 'uses different objects when false' do
  object1 = SomeClass.new
  object2 = SomeClass.new
  data = "something"

  MasterClass.register(object1)
  MasterClass.register(object2)

  #Not correct:
  expect(object1).to_not receive(:get_data).with(data) 
  expect(object2).to_not receive(:get_data).with(data)

  #False is supposed to mean 
  # "create new objects for each call to get_data for the SomeClass"
  MasterClass.distribute_data(data, false) 
end
```

I know I can test for equality on the object property with `a.equal?(b)`, but how can I do this when the object I want to test is a parameter within the`with` method in rspec mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of it that sticks to use of the "expect" syntax:

```
it 'uses different objects when false' do
  object1 = SomeClass.new
  object2 = SomeClass.new
  data = "something"

  MasterClass.register(object1)
  MasterClass.register(object2)

  arg1 = nil
  expect(object1).to receive(:get_data) {|arg| arg1 = arg}
  expect(object2).to receive(:get_data) {|arg| expect(arg).to_not equal(arg1)}

  #False is supposed to mean 
  # "create new objects for each call to get_data for the SomeClass"
  MasterClass.distribute_data(data, false) 
end
```

Comment: I needed to use `...expect(arg).to_not equal(arg1)` in stead of just `eq`. Apparently the `eq` is equivalent of `==` that checks the value, not the actual object.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is very interesting. If you want to check that the method is called with a specific object you also need to use this method, but changing to `.to equal(data)`. The normal `receive(:method).with(data)` does not test that the data is the same object.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, though, since `"foo".equal?("foo")` is `false` and you'd certainly want to match `eql?` strings. I'm not sure if RSpec uses `==` or `eql?`, but we can find which one it does you and you can redefine that operator for `SomeClass` if you'd like.

Comment: Did not quite understand what you meant by that, but if you have a look at [the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/equality-matchers) you can see that the `eq` uses `==`, and that `equal` is what I am looking for, namely `"string".to_not equal("string")`

Comment: My point probably wasn't worth making. I just meant that you could redefine `SomeClass`'s `==` operator to be the same as `equal?` if you wanted to use the `eq` matcher. But then, since classes default to having `==` the same as `equal?`, `SomeClass` by definition must have changed `==` for a reason and you wouldn't want to change it back.

Comment: I don't want to start monkey patching basic classes like the string. Much better to use the right comparator from the get-go.

Comment: I just realized I got confused with this thread. I was responding to your concern about the `with` operator. My questions about use of `==` vs. `eql?` and the possibility of changing `SomeClass` were in that context, not the context of RSpec's `eq` matcher. I'd also assumed `SomeClass` could have been some custom class of yours. I agree that monkey patching some basic class like `String` is not an option. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work,  adding a block to the `receive` matcher, and using the matcher `be`:

```
describe "Example" do
  it "should find something, but not using the original variable" do
    text = "Hi!"
    original = "!"
    copied = original.clone
    expect( text ).to receive(:include?) { |x| x.should_not be original; true }
    text.include?( copied ).should be_true
  end
end
```

Your equivalent might look like this:

```
expect(object1).to receive(:get_data) do |d| 
   d.should_not be data
   d.should == data
end
```